# PWA - Adicionar a tela inicial não funciona em localhost

Tags: html, android, pwa, service-worker

Estou tentando fazer o meu site mobile aparecer o botão "Adicionar a Tela Inicial" , mas não funciona de jeito nenhum.

Meus arquivos

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#BABACA">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
                alert('registrado');
                // Registration was successful
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                alert('deu problema' + err);
                // registration failed :(
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
            });
        });
    }



</script>
<body>
Pagina teste do pwa 2

</body>
</html>
```

manifest

```
{
  "name": "Site Teste",
  "short_name": "teste",
  "theme_color": "#2196f3",
  "background_color": "#2196f3",
  "display": "browser",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "teste_icon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ]
}
```

sw.json

```
{
  "name": "Site Teste",
  "short_name": "teste",
  "theme_color": "#2196f3",
  "background_color": "#2196f3",
  "display": "browser",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "teste_icon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ]
}
```

Meu site está em https e ele aparece o serviceworker funcionando , mesmo com self certificate , usei firefox

O ultimo teste que fiz  o download deste projeto
https://github.com/mdn/pwa-examples/tree/master/a2hs

Esse projeto funciona bem online
https://mdn.github.io/pwa-examples/a2hs/

Mas em localhost não.

Existe alguma limitação para adicionar pagina no localhost ?

Answer (score -1):

Não consegui achar solução, o que foi feito pra contornar o problema foi apontar a rota do servidor para o proprio servidor de desenvolvimento, ai ele entrava no site e o site apontava para o nosso servidor de desenv.